Is there any way to initialize a context with data from an api?
I'm trying to create a context whose default value will come from an external source. I would need to do something similar to doing the fetch outside of an asynchronous function (I don't think this is possible). The question is: how to perform fetch in this scenario?
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { Usuario } from "../typings/types";


interface UsuariosContextType {
    usuarios: Usuario[]
    setUsuario?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Usuario[]>>;
}

// I have no ideia how to do it the right way
const usuarios_data = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/usuarios`, { cache: 'no-store' })
const usuarios_array = await usuarios_data.json()
const usuarios_lista: Usuario[] = usuarios_array

export const UsuariosContext = createContext<UsuariosContextType>({ usuarios: usuarios_lista })

export const UsuariosProvider = (children: React.ReactNode) => {

    const [usuarios, setUsuario] = useState<Usuario[]>([])

    return (
        <UsuariosContext.Provider value={{ usuarios, setUsuario }}>
            {children}
        </UsuariosContext.Provider >
    )
}


To asynchronously load data and set it as a context value, you will need to use useEffect to load your data and a useState to control loading state (which you might use later to display a spinner).
In the snippet below, we make an API call in useEffect once the context component mounts. In the useEffect, we also set isLoading to true. Once the request is finished and parsed, we use finally to set isLoading to false.


import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Usuario } from "../typings/types";


interface UsuariosContextType {
    usuarios: Usuario[]
    setUsuario?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Usuario[]>>;
    isLoading: boolean;
}

export const UsuariosContext = createContext<UsuariosContextType>({ usuarios: [], isLoading: false })

export const UsuariosProvider = (children: React.ReactNode) => {

    const [usuarios, setUsuario] = useState<Usuario[]>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      fetch(`http://localhost:8080/usuarios`, { cache: 'no-store' })
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then(parsedData => setUsuario(parsedData))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }, []);

    return (
        <UsuariosContext.Provider value={{ usuarios, setUsuario, isLoading }}>
            {children}
        </UsuariosContext.Provider >
    )
}




In React, data fetching must be done inside an asynchronous function, which is not possible outside the component’s lifecycle methods. When initializing a context with external data, the fetch operation should be performed after the component mounts. To handle this, React provides hooks like useEffect() that allow you to run side effects (like fetching data) when the component is rendered.
I would recommend familiarizing yourself with the async nature of React and effects handling via useEffect() hook.

In react you fetch the external data within the effect hook that runs right after your component mounts, inside of the component lifecycle.
You also need to leverage useState() hook to store the fetched data.
useEffect() executes the fetch call and saves data into a state, that
will be represented withing your defined context.

Complete Solution
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode } from "react";
import { Usuario } from "../typings/types";

interface UsuariosContextType {
    usuarios: Usuario[];
    setUsuario?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Usuario[]>>;
}

export const UsuariosContext = createContext<UsuariosContextType>({ usuarios: [] });

export const UsuariosProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    const [usuarios, setUsuario] = useState<Usuario[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch the data when the component mounts
        const fetchUsuarios = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/usuarios`, { cache: 'no-store' });
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Failed to fetch usuarios");
                }
                const data: Usuario[] = await response.json();
                setUsuario(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching usuarios:", error);
            }
        };

        fetchUsuarios();
    }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this runs only once on mount

    return (
        <UsuariosContext.Provider value={{ usuarios, setUsuario }}>
            {children}
        </UsuariosContext.Provider>
    );
};



Context is not limited to static values. If you pass a different value on the next render, React will update all the components reading it below! This is why context is often used in combination with state.

Citation : Use cases for context
Therefore, Context combined with State enables the code to provide dynamic data from async sources. The following sample code does the same.
App.js
import { useEffect, useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react';

// user context
const userContext = createContext();

const App = () => {
  // user state, the state by which value will be given to the context
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // an async code invoking the state updater.
    // In production code, this will be a fetch call
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        setUser({
          name: 'A good Name',
          category: 'First Class',
          jobProfile: 'A Good job profile',
        }),
      1000
    );
  }, []); // Effect to work on mounting the component

  // user state has been used to provide value to the context
  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={user}>
      <UserInfo />
    </userContext.Provider>
  ); 
};

function UserInfo() {
  const user = useContext(userContext);
  if (!user) {
    return 'Loading..';
  }
  return (
    <>
      <label>User's information</label>
      <br />
      <label>Name : {user.name}</label>
      <br />
      <label>Category : {user.category}</label>
      <br />
      <label>Job Profile : {user.jobProfile}</label>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Test run
Browser display on load of the App

Browser display after user data has reached


You can do something like this
import  { createContext, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Usuario } from "../typings/types";

interface UsuariosContextType {
  usuarios?: Usuario[] | [];
  setUsuarios?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Usuario[]>>;
}

export const UsuariosContext = createContext<UsuariosContextType>({
  usuarios: [],
});

export const UsuariosProvider = (children: React.ReactNode) => {
  const [usuarios, setUsuarios] = useState<Usuario[] | []>([]);

  const fetchUsers = useCallback(async () => {
    const usuarios_data = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/usuarios`, {
      cache: "no-store",
    });
    const usuarios_array = await usuarios_data.json();
    setUsuarios(usuarios_array);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers()
  }, [fetchUsers])

  return (
    <UsuariosContext.Provider value={{ usuarios, setUsuarios }}>
      {children}
    </UsuariosContext.Provider>
  );
};

